# How to turn an old phone into a Chromecast Audio?

Tags: chromecast

I've been using my old Nexus 4 with cracked screen to play music from iTunes (shudder) to speakers. I'd like to be able to cast from my phone with Google Play Music to the Nexus instead.
I've tried CheapCast but it doesn't seem to work.
Anything else I could try or do I have to shell out €40 for a ChromeCast?